# How do I setup a connection to a database over a SSH-Tunnel with kerberos in a gui?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, gui, kerberos, mysql-connection

I need to connect to a Mysql database on a server that is only accessible over ssh with a Kerberos ticket. In a console this is easy, I only do:

```
kinit (then enter password)
ssh username@server (without entering password)
sudo su - (without entering password)
mysql (without user or password)
```

Now I want to view the content of the database with a gui like Mysql Workbench or PHPStorm but I don't know how to setup the connection.

I clicked (in PHPStorm) "Use SSH Tunnel", added the server in "Proxy host" and my username in "Proxy user".

Now I have to choose between Auth Type "password" or "key pair", but neither seems to be right for kerberos and whatever I try I just can't connect.

I tried with PHPStorm, MySQL Workbench and DBeaver which basically all offer the same options to setup an SSH-Tunnel.

There is a question about a SSH-Tunnel with MySQL Workbench here: [SSH tunnel via MySQL Workbench](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312452/ssh-tunnel-via-mysql-workbench), but it doesn't involve kerberos.